# removing extra white spaces from text files

Tags: java, regex, newline, removing-whitespace

I have number of text files in the following format:

```
196903274115371008    @266093898 

Prince George takes his first public steps with his mom,                              Catherine, Duchess of    

Cambridge.
```

I would like to remove all extra while spaces + new line characters except the first new line characters. So I would like to above to be like this:

```
196903274115371008@266093898 

Prince George takes his first public steps with his mom, Catherine, Duchess of Cambridge.
```

I wrote the following code :

```
package remove_white_space222;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Remove_white_space222 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfile.txt"); 
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            line = line.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace
            line=line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            fw.write(line);


        }
        fr.close();
        fw.close();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help,,,,

Comment: +1 for the clean code and explaination of what you want.. Seldom seen on SOF.

Comment: Will the second line always be blank in all your input files?

Answer (score 1):

```
    File file = new File("input_file.txt");
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("empty_file.txt")) {
        String st;
        while((st = br.readLine()) != null){
            fw.write(st.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().concat("\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfile.txt"); 
        String line;

        int lineNum = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            //check if we are working with the first two lines 
            //(which should remain untouched)
            if (lineNum > 1) {
                //make sure we ignore any empty lines
                if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                    //add a space to the end of each line to make 
                    //padding before we append the next line.
                    line=line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ") + " ";
                }
            } else {
                //remove all whitespace.
                line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");
                line = line + "\n";
            }
            fw.write(line);
            lineNum++;
        }
        fr.close();
        fw.close();
}
```

Output:

```
196903274115371008@266093898 

Prince George takes his first public steps with his mom, Catherine, Duchess of Cambridge. %
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use status via an enum to add newlines after first line and all empty lines following it.

```
package remove_white_space222;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.IOException;


public class Remove_white_space222 {

    enum Status {

        FIRST, EMPTY, NORMAL;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfile.txt"); 
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        { 
            line = line.trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace
            line=line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
            fw.write(line);
            if (status != Status.NORMAL) {
                if ((status == Status.FIRST) || line.isEmpty()) {
                    pw.println();
                    status = Status.EMPTY;
                } else {
                    status = Status.NORMAL;
                }
            }
        }
        fr.close();
        fw.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your logic for all the lines but line 1 (the 2nd line), just stick `"\n\n"` in that case, so you have an empty line.

Also, I'd advise to open your resources in the try this way you don't have to worry about closing them

```
try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfile.txt") ) {

    String line;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(lineNumber == 1) {
            line = "\n\n";
        } else {
            line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        }
        fw.write(line);
        lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> 196903274115371008 @266093898
>
> Prince George takes his first public steps with his mom, Catherine, Duchess ofCambridge.